# \foreach element of a table column

Tags: foreach

I want to code a `\foreach` for each element in the column `Label` of `my.dat`. Something like:

```
\foreach \L[count=\i] in column {Label} from {my.dat}
```

What is the right syntax? I can't find anywhere.

```
\begin{filecontents}{my.dat}
Label       Value
AS  1
JK  .9
OW  1.5
CU  3.1
TR  .5
\end{filecontents}
```

Comment: datatools package https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/datatool

Answer (score 4):

You could try `\csvloop` from the package `csvsimple`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\begin{filecontents*}{my.dat}
Label,Value
AS,1
JK,.9
OW,1.5
CU,3.1
TR,.5
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\csvloop{file={my.dat}, head to column names, command={\csvcoli\ is row number \thecsvrow\\}}
\end{document}
```

See the [csvsimple manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/csvsimple/csvsimple.pdf) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

`pgfplotstable` provides functions to read data and access to it in loops, and can be used inside TikZ pictures. For example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{my.dat}
Label       Value
AS  1
JK  .9
OW  1.5
CU  3.1
TR  .5
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
% First, read the table into a data structure
\pgfplotstableread{my.dat}{\MyData}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,circle, fill=red] (Origin) at (0,0) {};
% Following loop is equivalent to your proposed
% \foreach \L[count=\i] in column {Label} from {my.dat}
\pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{Label}\of\MyData\as\L{%
  \edef\i{\pgfplotstablerow}
  \draw (Origin) -- (60*\i:2) node[circle,draw,fill=orange!20] {\L};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Result]